# Multiple progress status + Ajax form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress

I'm using Ajax Form plugin, And I had a loop for send multiple requests.
I'm trying to get the individual progress of each file. Seems that works, but the progress of the files only show in the last `<p>` of the code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; i++) {
$('form').ajaxSubmit({
beforeSend: function() {
    $('body').append('<p class="c'+ i +'"></p>'); 
    var classe = '.c' + i;
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';

    $(classe).append(percentVal);
    //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
}
});
}
```

The HTML output for 2 files:

```
<p class="c0"/>
<p class="c1">
79%
100%
81%
100%
</p>
```

There's two `100%` that seems that it get the progress of the two files. But, it just print in the last element.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because classe change to c1 before the response from c0 come in... 
Put it into a anonym function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var classe = '.c' + i;
        $('form').ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('body').append('<p class="c' + i + '"></p>');
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';

                $(classe).append(percentVal);
                //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
            }
        });
    }());
}
```

(NOT TESTED)

Or you have to change the Ajax request to sync